# Repository/Updating/Upgrading Issue

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, updates

The other day I was asked to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10, at the time I was busy and hit no.  I can not upgrade/update at this point, I get (error -11) or a 404 in terminal.  In the software updater I get 'failed to download repository information.'

I have tried changing my "Download From" setting to "Best" to "Main" and even a few other countries.  And in "Other Software" I have tried disabling packages, but doesn't seem to help what so ever. I have tried several of the other commands to try and fix it, such as `-fix missing` or sudo `apt-get update clean`.

P.S. This has also affected my thunderbird client, I cannot send/receive emails.

Here is my error log when trying to upgrade:

```
jakob@Skeletor:~$ sudo update-manager -d

gpg: /tmp/tmpvejqvl/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: /tmp/tmpnayby6/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 483, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(excep)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 86, in commit
    True, close_on_done)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 483, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(excep)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 158, in _run_in_dialog
    yield trans.run()
aptdaemon.errors.TransactionFailed: Transaction failed: Package does not exist
 Package linux-headers-3.8.0-33 isn't available
gpg: /tmp/tmp3kw_hl/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created.
```

And let me throw in my sudo apt-get update too.  Which this has been working variably too, but I don't know what to change my repositories to, and disabling does not effect:

[image]

```
 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is the short version, but looks exactly like this fairly consistently.  Sometimes it downloads, sometimes it doesn't.  Sometimes it tells me I have an update, and doesn't do anything.

If it helps, I have recently had issues trying to install Samba as well, and connecting to the office's NAS Drive.  Which works now, but I had to edit `/etc/fstab/` and a few other things trying to get that to work as well.  I understand it could also be a DNS problem, but this has been going on for a few days, as well as I've already tried changing my DNS server via my computer, however I am not allowed to alter the DNS on our company's router.

Comment: What happens when you disable the two Launchpad ppa's? They could be down. You can re-enable them as soon as you upgrade.

Comment: If I disable them, such as my "wine ppa" it will still continue trying to update, its kinda bizarre.  I am not a linux-expert by any means, but I have a rough idea of how it all works

Comment: You still get the "something wicked happens" errors when you disable them and run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Yes, those vary based upon server, but not based upon which packages I have selected.  (If I turn off wine, it still tries to update that).

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you have mixed packages 32 and 64 bits. Your kernel is improperly installed  : linux-headers-3.8.0-33

Desactive ppa and launch this command :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Send the result

Comment: First: http://i.imgur.com/IPao79g.png

Comment: Second: http://i.imgur.com/klQ24Vq.png  Wasn't sure which I should disable, so I did both, same results.

Comment: Does this help at all?  When I was trying to connect to my NAS drive in the office, I did edit quite a few internet related settings.  I cannot remember all of them, but I have already restored /etc/fstab to its default (and I don't think that was the problem either).  Deleting the lock files will help temporarily.